# If I need more custom functionality can I manually write HTML forms?

Tags: python, django

I started coding a couple years ago but it's all been in Python and I never learned HTML/CSS real in-depth.

I've now got a decent grasp of Django and somewhat of how the data gets passed around Django but I've noticed some limitations to the functionality I am trying to achieve using Djangos forms module. I think it would help better if I understood the front-end better.

This has got my attention so I started to try learning about front-end frameworks like react.js, as well as HTML/CSS/vanillaJS. Today I'm a couple hundred pages deep into an HTML book and finding out more about forms than I knew. I've always seen the forms from the Django side (other than a few manual HTML forms I write every now and then).

So I guess my question is, and it might be stupid, can I simply render a function based or CBV for that matter and pass the context I need and do fully custom forms in the front-end? Then grab that data back in the view using `request.GET`? How to handle form validation like this? Is this one way of expanding the functionality of Django if I'm reaching limitations?

I know it sounds self-explanatory but I want to be sure I'm not missing something. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Method**

You can manually design your front-end forms using HTML. After that get data from front-end using request.post.
After that everything happens into your views instead of separate object.

1. Get your data from request.
2. Clean and validating your data.
3. Saving into database.

**2nd Method**

Using django forms classes to build custom forms in Python. 
Adding html,css properties, cleaning and validations at one place basically encapsulating your forms.

**Forms in Django :**

1. Simple forms
2. Model forms

You can use both of them according to your requirements.

**2nd approach is good because**

- Code readable
- Simple
- Modular
- No complexity
- Time saving
- Purely in Python

---

**See also**

[django forms official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the response.  I have read the Django docs but it has left me without an understanding of the front-end. I found some limitations when my project began to require a nested formset to get even the basic functionality of what I want - and even then it would be much easier if I could just manually write custom HTML forms and pass the context of what I need to those forms, then after form submission, clean, validate, save. And it seems this can be done with what you are saying. Are the Simple Forms you speak of the base class of ModelForms, etc? i.e. `forms.Form`

Comment: I would like to add that most scenarios I will still use Django's Forms module but what I am looking for is to be able to go outside this module when I find limitations. I do not want to spend days trying to find work-arounds in the Forms module. I simply don't have the time for that. It seems that the Django Forms module is simply a way of constructing the HTML in a 'boilerplate' fashion (using the factory method), correct?